# Android move slide down to slide up view

Tags: java, android, android-animation, slideup, motionevent

I'm using [this library](https://github.com/loeschg/android-slide-down-view) to use slide down menu, the problem is when I want to move the handle from top to bottom and want to change from slide down to slide up, I try to change the variable but can't make it right

This is the original code

```
/* User tapped down on screen. */
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        // User has tapped the screen
                        yStart = event.getRawY();
                        lastY = event.getRawY();
                        currentHeight = slideDownView.getHeight();
                        break;

                    /* User is dragging finger. */
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                        // Calculate the total height change thus far.
                        float totalHeightDiff = event.getRawY() - yStart;

                        // Adjust the slide down height immediately with touch movements.
                        LayoutParams params = slideDownView.getLayoutParams();
                        params.height = (int)(currentHeight + totalHeightDiff);
                        slideDownView.setLayoutParams(params);

                        // Check and set which direction drag is moving.
                        if (event.getRawY() > lastY) {
                            directionDown = true;
                        } else {
                            directionDown = false;
                        }

                        // Set the lastY for comparison in the next ACTION_MOVE event.
                        lastY = event.getRawY();
                        break;

                    /* User lifted up finger. */
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                        /*
                         * Need to snap either up or down. Using ValueAnimator to "finish" the action. 
                         * HeightEvaluator is a custom class. 
                         * 
                         * NOTE: I'm using the nineoldandroids library for 
                         */
                        if (directionDown) {

                            // Open the sliding view.
                            int startHeight = slideDownView.getHeight(); 

                            ValueAnimator animation = ValueAnimator.ofObject(
                                    new HeightEvaluator(slideDownView),
                                    startHeight, 
                                    (int) openHeight).setDuration(300);

                            // See Table 3 for other interpolator options 
                            // - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html
                            animation.setInterpolator(new OvershootInterpolator(1));
                            animation.start();

                        } else {

                            // Close the sliding view.
                            int startHeight = slideDownView.getHeight(); 
                            ValueAnimator animation = ValueAnimator.ofObject(
                                    new HeightEvaluator(slideDownView),
                                    startHeight, 
                                    (int) closedHeight).setDuration(300);
                            animation.setInterpolator(new OvershootInterpolator(1));
                            animation.start();
                        }
                        break;
```

How to make it reverse ? so I can slide up from bottom to top ? is it have to change also in `HeightEvaluator.java` ?

Comment: this lib not update in last 5 year. i hope you have to use https://www.androidauthority.com/bottom-sheets-707252/.

Comment: @KuLdipPaTel what I want to use is that the button at the bottom of the parent and when I click or drag it the button also push to the top with the slide view

Comment: This may help you:

http://snipplr.com/view/39078/android-animation-slidedown-slideup/
https://developerlife.com/2008/08/05/android-animation-framework/

Comment: @Jackeykabra non of above link have a explanation about if button at bottom and slide up the button also being push along with the slideView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I use BottomSheet and set PeekHeight to make a slideUp with button at the bottom that still visible to trigger the slideView